# How to convert DataFrame to DynamicFrame object in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I'm trying to convert some of my pySpark code to Scala to improve performance.  In AWS Glue (which uses Apache Spark) a script is automatically generated for you and it typically uses the `DynamicFrame` object to load, transform and write data out.  However, the `DynamicFrame` class does not have all of the same functionalities as the `DataFrame` class and at times you have to convert back to a DataFrame object and vice versa to perform certain operations.  Below is how I have converted from `DataFrame` to `DynamicFrame` objects in pySpark:

```
    // PySpark version
    // datasource is a DynamicFrame object
    datasource0 = datasource.toDF().limit(5000000)
    applymapping1 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(datasource0, glueContext, "applymapping1")
```

Is there an equivalent function to `fromDF` in Scala to revert back to a `DynamicFrame` object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DynamicFrame` object has an [`apply` method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-dynamicframe-object.html#glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-dynamicframe-object-defs-apply):

```
val dynamicFrame = DynamicFrame(dataframe, glueContext)
```

Comment: Thanks @botchniaque .  This works and my code is up and running now. :)